# XLS/XLSX to CSV in c++

Tags: c++, csv, xls, xlsx

I've been given a project in which I need to import data from CSV, XLS and XLSX files, do some processing, then write the results to a database.

I'm working on a project that's been going on for a while and there are several import functions already that use a very nice object to handle opening files with all sorts of separators and such. And this object is key to the processing that I need to perform.

Since a CSV is basically a textfile with a different extension this object opens it perfectly and I've managed to complete most of the processing and testing with the object and values stored within.

But now I need to add the XLS and XLSX support. And since this object is now pretty much central to the processing I figured the easiest way to fit XLS and XLSX files in would be to convert them to CSV, then import that.

Any help would be appreciated and I'll try answer questions if it's necessary, but since the request is just for some way to convert from one file type to another and nothing more insightful I don't think it's really necessary to add any snippets just yet.

Comment: If you can run to Perl, there are modules on CPAN that can turn XLS/XLSX into CSV.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It'd need to be a part of the program. Probably something I'd link to and just call up to convert the file from XLS/XLSX if the user selects excel file when importing. Then it'd work with the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Your options in terms of C++ libraries:

- OpenXLSX - https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX
- XLNT - https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt

---

Or you could give "XLSX I/O" a try. It's a small C library.

- "XLSX I/O" - https://github.com/brechtsanders/xlsxio

Don't forget to add the usual `extern "C"`, when calling C functions from C++.

The repo contains basic xlsx-to-csv (and csv-to-xlsx) examples, which should get you started: https://github.com/brechtsanders/xlsxio/blob/master/src/xlsxio_xlsx2csv.c

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library

Also you can use libraries from Open/Libre Office project.

Comment: I've been poking around and I've seen that library multiple times and I have the same issue with it as everyone else. It's only a demo version that gets pretty annoying pretty fast. And I don't need that much functionality that I'd buy it. I just need to get the text data from the cells, not all the formatting. I'm not even writing to an excel file. Not worth.